# I have been drinking a potion to stop a transformation. One day, I stopped drinking the potion. How would the transformation take place?

Tags: magic, humans, humanoid, shapeshifters

I am a half-human half-dragon hybrid that has been intaking "medicine" since I was a child.

Unbeknownst to me, the "medicine" I am actually taking is a transformation potion to suppress my "dragon" traits since childhood. Therefore, making me appear like a regular human without scales, horn, wings, and tail. Just a perfectly normal human. The dragon qualities are absent at birth and would only show first signs from a certain age marker. Kinda like puberty.

One day, I stopped drinking this medicine. This the point where my dragon traits should be mature. How would my dragon qualities start to appear? How will the transformation likely take place? Would it be drastic, gradual, or something else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no real-life case studies involving suppression of transformation into dragons or any other animal. :P

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll reword my question  Edit: Completely removed that misleading part :))

Comment: @MasonWheeler But there are real life drugs that involve suppressing the transformation from childhood to adulthood that happens during puberty, so it's not so silly of a question. This potion would likely work the same way except on the dragon traits instead of the secondary sexual traits.

Comment: I agree with @AndyD273 and am voting to leave this question open.

Comment: What about something like the contraceptive pill? Some people take it to regulate/lighten their periods, then when they come off the pill, these new effects continue. For others, they revert to irregular/heavy periods - or somewhere in between. Depending on the base of your medicine, it could remain in the system for weeks/months (or could simply have become habitual for the body) - but equally could wear off really quickly if a strong dose is required to suppress the transformation.

Comment: I am new here, found this master piece of starting scenario and it's `put on hold` damn. But maybe the comment section is enough. I would prefer a slow developing transformation.. including a tragedy. Like when he was sleeping, he spit a small spark that made his home burn, but he survived. A few years later his smell and taste skills improve a big amount and his nails feel way stronger like they could destroy stone just by scratching on it. He gets backpain and his eye sigh become much clearer (wears glasses at first). Eventuelly he starts breath fire when he has hicubs and learns controlling

Comment: @CagatayUlubay It's off hold if you want to move this to an answer.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question.  There are no real life human-dragon people to extrapolate from.  Dragons aren't real so anything about their biology is pure speculation (and isn't described in any detail).  Also unstated is how long the transformation potion takes to metabolize out. And, we don't know the growth rate of dragon characteristics.  Given this lack of detail, the only answer is "The transformation takes as long as the author wants to serve the story."

Comment: Cool scenario though.

Answer (score 5):

This is interesting... My guess would be more gradual, over weeks and months, since that's how the body generally grows, but I also don't know how much magic is involved in the transformation.

If the character is fully  mature now, changes might be very slow, since the body wouldn't be growing as much. If they are a teenager then it might be faster with all the hormones and other growth stuff.

Though if the medicine is just a hormone suppressant then changes could still happen into maturity.

I think you could make the case that some changes would happen faster than others; skin hardening into scales might be fast, while growing and reshaping bone would be slower.
But a lot of that depends on how much magic is involved in both the transformation and the suppression.

I think you could make the case for it going either way, depending on what fits your narrative best.

Comment: I deleted a part of my question wherein I am asking for some real-life examples, or case studies not particularly about dragon transformation (because we all know it is not real), but something similar that we might help compare in this scenario. Do you think I should modify my question to not let it be too opinion-based?

Comment: @Bwrites There are hormone suppressing drugs that can be used to slow/stop the growth of secondary sexual characteristics that would take place in puberty, such as the growth of breasts. The potion could work in the same way, blocking the specific hormone that causes the transformation. If that's the case the characteristics could still develop later if the medicine is stopped in time, or if something else causes the hormones to start again, like how pregnancy can cause an increase in breast tissue growth even in fully mature women.

Answer (score 3):

The only sensible answer is, "However you want."

Look, it's not like there is a body of experience on this subject. Or anything remotely similar. So, write what you like. If you want to limit your world as much as possible to mundane reality, then I'd vote for gradual transformation. Probably changes in skin and personality first.

On the other hand, you're clearly talking about magic, and if it follows everyday rules it ain't magic. A Hulk-like transformation would make for a pretty good story, don't you think?

Comment: Well, the only "sensible" answer is "whatever answer fits the historical / natural / magical / thaumoscientific circumstances of the world in question."

Comment: @elemtilas - How does your version differ from mine?

Comment: It differs considerably, actually. One leaves the answer to the vagrant whims of the author. The other constrains the author to the nature of the world. I probably should have put a ";)" on that response --- both modalities have their place in worldbuilding and writing from such worlds. And since we're dealing with otherworlds of one kind or another, neither answer is actually "sensible"!  :)

Comment: @elemtilas - So what, exactly, is " the nature of the world" when it comes to dragon/human hybrids which change from one to the other? And where, exactly, did you discover this fascinating information?

Comment: You'll have to ask Bwrites about the nature of his world. I can only speak for mine, as somewhat revealed in my answer to his question. Generally speaking, the nature of any otherworld is in part what the author makes it to be but is mostly what the author discovers was already there.

Answer (score 2):

Much will depend upon the nature of the world you inhabit. The way things work, you see. Your question happens to have crossed over the Wonchaunce Barrier and into a world where (most) people don't know much at all about dragons, to say nothing of the poor sod who's a weredrake and is trying (or perhaps whose parents wanted him) to pass for entirely human in nature.

Now, in [**The World**](http://aveneca.com/cbb/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=4585), there are dragons of various sorts. Most are relatively small (like [**this dragonet**](https://elemtilas.deviantart.com/art/Daine-Girl-With-Dragonet-649122333)) and very few kindreds that I'm aware of sport scales such as you're familiar with. Like this little fellow, most dragons sport feathers in a wide array of shapes, colours, hues and lengths. Your average dragon in The World is a veritable Mardi Gras float all unto himself.

There are also various conditions (some entirely mundane others more thaumic in nature) that may require some kind of dwimcrafty potion to cure or at least mitigate symptoms. I am not aware of any kind of human-dragon hybridisation occurring in Gea, but there are other similar hybrids in existence. Skinchangers, for example, are one sort. These folks have an extrinsic magical ability to change the form & appearance of their bodies. Werepigs and Werehounds, for example, are another sort. These folks have an inborn, geno-phenotypical expression of two different sorts of beings. Much like a wild chimera, these folks express within their physical beings aspects of both sides of their heritage. Werehounds, for example, pass relatively easily for Men, but they have doggy ears and a slightly pronounced & doggy face. Their smiles, when they smile at all, confirms the suspicion. Werepigs are a very low-brow kind of person, more beast than intelligent creature. Their overall form is like a very burly Man, but their snouts, tusks and bristles give away their boarish heritage.

Now, in Gea, it is possible to obtain, generally at great expence (both in hard money and also in side effects suffered), certain medicinal potions that can dampen or even eradicate an extrinsic characteristic. Generally speaking, it is not possible at all to eradicate the hybridism of the latter. And the reason is quite simple: the one is an ability, while it arises from the curious alchemy of mind, magic and genes, it is a variable and alterable characteristic of a person. It can be improved or repressed by external helps --- practice makes perfect, but this potion makes moot! The latter is the physical expression of the genetic code of an individual. And while Lamarck has a greater say than Darwin in many matters, even ordinary magic can not alter how many limbs and fingers and hearts a person is supposed to have. So it would be if you were born in Gea. A potion might suppress secondary characteristics, such as the growth of flamboyant red and blue feathers down your spine, no potion could alter the basic form and substance of a weredrake.

Generally speaking, once you stop drinking such a potion, it ceases to be effectual. Whatever it was designed to prevent from sprouting will begin sprouting, because that's what your genes are telling your body to sprout. It may be slightly uncomfortable at first to find long feathers growing from your crest and spine, or wings growing from your scapulas, but you'll soon get used to it! Just remember, in many jurisdictions around the polyverse, your gently used but no longer needed shirts will be a tidy and tax deductible charitable donation!

As for natural philosophical studies into the matter in general, you might consider Limberjack & Wonstable's foundational research into the *Alterable & Inalterable Characteriſtics of the Werebeast with Particular Attention to Thoſe Changes of Early Development* (Univ. of Auntimoany, 1944). Also, there is an earlier anecdotal work by Ybricg-Silverorn, that is, *Life of the Halfborn: Tales of Well Known Werefolk* (Wootman & Sellars, 1794).

Answer (score 0):

I expect it would be gradual, once the transformation potion is stopped. It seems unlikely that you would suddenly spring into dragonhood after having never been a fully developed dragon.

Of course, I cannot prove that, but the Axolotl has two possible adult forms, normally aquatic retaining larval attributes, it can spontaneously though rarely develop into a land living salamander. Perhaps this kind of ability to suddenly develop differently is relevant.

http://www.axolotl.org/